# Расширить объем vdi в virtualbox

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Есть виртуалка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иногда по мере надобности я ее увеличиваю командой `VBoxManage modifyhd “C:\Users\User\VirtualBox VMs\Windows 7\Windows 7.vdi” --resize x` после чего захожу на нее, расширяю том и все отлично.

Последний раз ее увеличил до 57GB, после чего зашел на виртуалку, а там [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И возможности расширить том нет и 57-42=15GB не понятно куда пропали.

**Вопрос:**

Куда пропала память (или что с ней случилось) и можно ли ее вернуть с тем чтобы расширить таки том?

P.S. Вот что выдает акронис

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вы пробовали чем-то проверить сторонним от винды? каким-нибудь акронисом например?

Comment: @Andrew, не пробовал, от вас первый раз про акронис услышал, добавил в вопрос то, что выдал акронис.

Comment: Хм... а если через `gparted live`?